# Get Type from class member

Tags: c++

I have to following scenario:

```
template< typename Type >
class FooBar
{
  public:
  std::vector< Type > bar;
};
```

and I want to get the `Type`, thought it would be possible with:

```
using vt = typename FooBar::bar::value_type;
```

but I'm getting: **no type named 'bar' in** .. compiler error.

Comment: Hint : *which* `FooBar` ?

Comment: @Roby, what exactly are you trying to do? Where do you declare vt?

Comment: You may also add `using value_type = Type;` in `FooBar` to allow `FooBar<T>::value_type`

Comment: @Jarod42, thanks good point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you cannot look into `FooBar` as that is not a type. It's a template. To obtain a type, you need to "apply" the template: `FooBar<T>` for some type `T`. If you don't want to hard code `T`, you need to make `vt` a template, too.

```
template<typename T>
using vt = typename decltype(FooBar<T>::bar)::value_type;
```

In your code, `bar` is the name of a member field. To access "contents" of the respective class, you need to obtain it's type. This is done using `decltype`.

[In action here.](http://ideone.com/CykAmj)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `FooBar` as a helper:

```
template <typename Type>
class FooBar {
public:
    using ID = vector<Type>;
};
```

In another template function you can use the helper to get the type:

```
// vector of int
typename FooBar<int>::ID vec;
```

Small example:

```
template <typename T>
void func()
{
    typename FooBar<int>::ID vec;
    for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i) {
        vec.push_back(i);
        cout << vec[i] << endl;
    }
}
```